# Logistic equation showing $L/2$ has the most rapid increase on the interval $0<y(0)<L$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So the question goes as follows:

"Show that a solution $y(t)$ of the logistic equation having  $0<y(0)<L$ is increasing most rapidly when its value is $L/2$.(Hint: You do not need to use the formula for the solution to see this)"

So first of all I don't unnderstand how you would be able to see this without utilizing the formula:

$\frac{dy}{dt}=ky(1-\frac{y}{L})$

And also most important how would you see that the increase is as most rapid att $t=L/2$?

I was thinking about taking the difference between the slope at $t=L/2$ and the other $t$ values on the interval. But it does't seem right.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that we are only concerned about $$0<y<L$$ Since $$y'=ky(1-\frac{y}{L})>0$$ we have $$y''=ky'(1-\frac{2y}{L})$$  and $$y'''=\frac {-2k}{L}y'^2<0$$ Notice that the only critical point of $y'$ is at $$y=\frac {L}{2}$$This critical point is a maximum because $y'$ is concave down due to the fact that its second derivative, $y'''$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is the rate of change of $y(t)$, so $y(t)$ is increasing most rapidly when $\frac{dy}{dt}$ has its maximum value. Since $\frac{dy}{dt}$ depends on $y$ only, we can use differentiation to find the maximum point:
$$
\left( ky\left(1-\frac{y}{L}\right) \right)'=k\left( 1-\frac{y}{L}+y\left(-\frac{1}{L}\right) \right)=k\left( 1-\frac{2y}{L} \right)
$$
We can see that $y=L/2$ is the only possible extremum point; $\frac{dy}{dt}$ strictly increases when $y<L/2$ and strictly decreases when $y>L/2$, thus $L/2$ is the maximum point.